# Input 0 of layer simple_rnn_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying for multi-class classification and here are the details of my training input and output. I have looked at other posts/Answers but not able to figure out. Thanks for your help.

```
**vectorized_data['train_sents']   #This is how the train data looks like
array([[[   1,    1,    1, ...,    1,    1,    1],
        [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
        [5818, 7142, 2467, ..., 7927, 7927, 7927],
        [  10,   19,    6, ...,   22,   22,   22],
        [   6,    6,    6, ...,    8,    8,    8],
        [   0,    0,    0, ..., 7927, 7927, 7927]],

       [[1108, 1108, 1108, ..., 1108, 1108, 1108],
        [   0,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
        [2244, 1362,  904, ..., 7927, 7927, 7927],
        [   0,    0,   13, ...,   22,   22,   22],
        [   3,    9,    6, ...,    8,    8,    8],
        [   0,    0,    0, ..., 7927, 7927, 7927]]])

vectorized_data['train_sents'].shape
(2522, 6, 67)

vectorized_data['train_lab'] # Labels data
array([[46, 46,  7, ..., 25, 25, 25],
       [46, 46, 46, ..., 25, 25, 25],
       [46, 11,  3, ..., 25, 25, 25],
       ...,
       [46, 46, 46, ..., 25, 25, 25],
       [ 7, 31, 31, ..., 25, 25, 25],
       [ 7, 31, 46, ..., 25, 25, 25]])

vectorized_data['train_lab'].shape
(2522, 67)

#Define Batch size
train_batch_size = 32
valid_batch_size = 64
test_batch_size = 64

max_seq_len = 124 #Define max_length of 124 for padding sentences and labels 
EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
epochs = 5
hidden = 256 #no of neurons
lr = .0001 # learning rate

batched_train_dataset
<BatchDataset shapes: ((32, 6, 67), (32, 67)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>

#Define RNN Simple model
class RNN_Simple(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, max_seq_len, embed_input_dim, embed_output_dim, num_labels, weights):
    super(RNN_Simple, self).__init__()
    self.embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=embed_input_dim, output_dim=embed_output_dim, 
                     weights=weights, input_length=max_seq_len, trainable=False, mask_zero=True)

    self.rnnsimple = layers.SimpleRNN(hidden, return_sequences=True) #Define hidden layer with 256 units

    self.dense = layers.Dense(num_labels, activation = 'softmax')

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.embedding(inputs) 
    x = self.rnnsimple(x) 
    logits = self.dense(x)
    return logits

# Run RNN Simple model
model = RNN_Simple(max_seq_len=max_seq_len,embed_input_dim=len(vocab), embed_output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embed_weights], num_labels=len(indicies))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr) #use Adam Optimizer with learning rate = .0001
sccel = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) #sparse categorical cross-entropy loss

# Train the RNN Simpl model. Calculate Loss.
train_loss_m = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('training_loss', dtype=tf.float32)
valid_loss_m = tf.keras.metrics.Mean('valid_loss', dtype=tf.float32)

def train_func(sent_batch, labels_batch):
  '''
   This function applies gradients and calculates loss for training dataset
   '''
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(sent_batch)
    loss = sccel(labels_batch, logits)
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(list(zip(grads,   model.trainable_variables)))
  return loss, logits**
```

It is failing in this function on >>>>>> logits = model(sent_batch)

```
 def train_func(sent_batch, labels_batch):
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(sent_batch)
```

The Error is:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer simple_rnn_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (32, 6, 67, 300)

Comment: `sent_batch` is expected to be 3 dims `(32, 6, 67)`, but it is 4 dims `(32, 6, 67, 300)`. Better to check the summary of your model. Most probably for embedding layer the output shape is `(None, 6, 67)` which is 3 dims. As a result, having 4 dims `(32, 6, 67, 300)` is not correct. Your sent_batch has to be 3dims. If it has to be 4 dims, then you should change the shape of the embedding.

Comment: Here are the shapes being passed. sent_batch = TensorShape([32, 6, 67]). labels_batch.shape = TensorShape([32, 67]). embed_weights.shape = (8044, 300)

Comment: Could you please provide the following values so I can see your model; `len(indicies)`, `len(vocab)`, `embed_weights.shape` (I think it is `(8044,300)`). By this way, I can find where exactly this error raises.

Comment: len(indicies) =4, len(revindicies) = 4, len(vocab) = 8044,

Comment: embed_weights.shape = (8044, 300). When we call the model the embedding shape changes to (32, 6, 67, 300)